# Google Sheets lstrip(), rstrip() equivalents?

Tags: google-sheets

What's the best way to turn

```
*3.32*
```

into

```
 3.32
```

In Google Sheets?  I want the string to go into a function to convert it into a number.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXEXTRACT`?  Something similar to `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+")` should do it.

Comment: That should work.  I was mentally stuck in Python with `lstrip()` `rstrip()`.

Comment: Please checkout [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Comment: @pnuts, I wound up using the SUBSTITUTE function

Comment: @Rubén, now bookmarked.  Thanks!

Comment: Not certain how a google-spreadsheets tagged question about google-spreadsheets is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215) function.

```
 =SUBSTITUTE("*3.32*","*","")
```